# Enabling Extended Desktop in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, extended-desktop, amd-radeon

How do I enable the extended desktop in Windows 7 Professional?  I have a AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series graphics card, which supports up to three monitors.  I have three monitors connected, but only one is working.

Comment: Do you have literature that says your card will support three monitors?  Typically a card with two DVI port and one HDMI port will only support two monitors at any given time.  Unless ATI has done something new the HDMI port uses the same circuitry as on of the DVI ports, so only two monitors at a time with one card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Display Port needs to be used to enable a third monitor.

> To enable more than two displays,
>   additional panels with native
>   DisplayPort™ connectors, and/or
>   DisplayPort™ compliant active adapters
>   to convert your monitor’s native input
>   to your cards DisplayPort™ or
>   Mini-DisplayPort™ connector(s), are
>   required.

-- [AMD Radeon](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/amd-radeon-hd-6000/hd-6850/Pages/amd-radeon-hd-6850-overview.aspx#4)

Answer (score 5):

Right click the *Desktop* then select *Screen Resolution*.

The displays should show up there and allow you to modify the behavior.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I found the settings through the Control Panel, and I was able to extend the desktop to a second monitor, so that any two monitors are in use with the extended desktop. However, it won't let me extend the desktop onto the third monitor. It turns out that I need to use the display port to use a third monitor.